# Sources for emission spectra

Tags: spectroscopy, photon-emission

I'm currently looking at a spectrum from a [balmer lamp](https://klingereducational.com/products/45113-balmer-lamp?_pos=1&_sid=2258ce2dc&_ss=r) with clear lines for H-alpha through H-gamma.

But there are additional, non-hydrogen lines at 774 nm and 842 nm. I assume that they are oxygen lines ("water vapour filling" of the tube), but I have a very hard time to find data about oxygen spectral lines. The NIST has several sources (e.g. https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Handbook/Tables/oxygentable2.htm), but there are lots of "strong" lines and none of them fits my data...

Comment: Nitrogen at 884 nm and 776 nm?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the lines you are seeing are *molecular* rather than *atomic* lines. For example, see Figure 1 of the paper attached [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.02528). The horizontal axis is plotted in a unit that is basically $1/\lambda$, so the features around 13,000 wavenumbers correspond to $\lambda \approx 770$ nm and the features around 11,700 wavenumbers correspond to $\lambda \approx 850$ nm. Of course, there could also be water, diatomic oxygen, etc. in your lamp.